# how to get currently viewing viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

When a push notification arrives, i need to get currently viewing `ViewController` from the method `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` of AppDelegate. I have been using both `TabbarController` and `NavigationController` in my App. When i try to get it from navigation stack (top item), i get my `CustomNavigationController`. But i need to get the viewing ViewController (might be an item in tabbar). Would you please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, post your code

Comment: Have you try `NSLog(@"%@", [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController.visibleViewController class]);`

Answer (score 0):

Just make a variable in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear for tabBar and set it in appdelegate.

You can check using this current viewController being viewed.